# why is the slug not saved in Strapi?

Tags: vue.js, strapi, slug

there is a video content type field in which there is a link slug, and when a new video is created, in the get request we get a null slug. tell me what's the matter. didn't install slugify

[docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/guides/slug.html)

[image: strapi img]

[image: get img]

Comment: It's unknown why this happens in your case. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @EstusFlask added images so you can see

Comment: which version are you using? I mean v4 or v3

Comment: @Manishyadav strapi v4

Comment: try using `slugify` might solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

getting stuck at getting `{slug : null}` after api call in strapi?

ok, this is what I did

I made a variable before POST request based on one of my form fields (eg:name field)
my formValues is an object with values of form fields like this

`formValues = {name:"whatever" , decsription:"whatever"}`

make a variable:

`const slug = formValues.name.split(" ").join("-") + "-" + Math.random();`

now we might have same names, so that's why I used a random value (you might want to use uuid or something like that)

then you send it like this

```
const res = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/events`,{...formValues, slug }); 
// you may not need to send an object with the shape like this 
// but the point is you concat your custom slug to the object you want to send
```

**notice** I'm adding a custom slug from frontend which is somehow random but based off of one of the fields, but it doesn't really matter, right now strapi does not have any documentation about this common problem, it seems like the best solution might be using`strapi-plugin-slugify` but if that didn't work for you feel free to use my solution